# How to send email to multiple user in SharePoint Online using C#

Tags: c#, email, sharepoint, csom

I am writing one code where i need to send an email to all the users who are active in respective SharePoint Site. All the active users has been stored in an Array/List Collection. But I am unable to pass that array value in `mailProps.To = new string[] { Array Input};`  I know we can manually enter multiple emails but these entries need to be entered through an array. Can any one help me that how to pass the multiple values in `mailProps.To = new string[] { Array Input};` through an array or List Collection.

```
`
EmailProperties mailProps = new EmailProperties();
mailProps.From = "myem@gmail.com";
mailProps.To = new string[] { Array Input};
mailProps.Subject = "Subject;
mailProps.Body = "Body"
Utility.SendEmail(ctx, mailProps);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();`
```

Comment: I can send the email but the email is getting triggered only to last person in array.

Comment: Use foreach loop to get all email id with remove ; with use replace method .

Comment: Could you please provide any reference snippet for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since all users have been stored in Array/List Collection, what you want is to get their email addresses then compact an Array for "mailProps.To".

You can have a try below quick medthod:

```
UserList.Select(x=>x.Email).ToArray();
```

BR